# LocalStorage on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html, local-storage

i have page register here
and i wanna use LocalStorage to show email verifiaction after register.
but i still confuse with method after click and before click.

i have notification here

```
<div class="alert success">
```

and i have input button here

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default size-new-account" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Create new account', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
```

i set a localstorage on script like

```
localStorage.setItem('register1','.alert.success');
jQuery('input.btn.btn-default.size-new-account').click(function(){
var reg = localStorage.getItem('register1');
});
```

but it wont works.
the div notification i set display: none; in .css

Comment: You read the localstorage and do nothing with it...

Comment: Well a submit button submits and you do not stop the action.

Comment: actually i use console.log(reg). but the console wont show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocalStorage` not for showing or hiding element, it store string, use `.show()`, `.hide()` instead

```js
localStorage.setItem('register1', 'Im string from localStorage');
jQuery('input.btn.btn-default.size-new-account').click(function() {
  var reg = localStorage.getItem('register1');
  $('.alert.success').html(reg);
  $('.alert.success').show();
});
```

```css
.alert.success {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert success">I'm hidden</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default size-new-account" value="submit" />
```

Comment: it wont show here because security error, try on https://jsfiddle.net/ewwink/7oz7ydLn/

Comment: it show, but span inside div wont show, and replace by Im string from localStorage. but i have <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> and <strong>Registration Success!</strong> Check Email. inside div

Comment: and if i clicked event it wrong, it still show success

Comment: anw, why all span and strong wont show? and it replace by  Im string from localStorage

Comment: by doing `$('.alert.success').html(reg);` all content inside class `.alert.success` will be overwritten, that's why it wont show